# Device font cpi option only shown in crystal report font properties

Tags: vba, visual-studio, crystal-reports-xi

Creating a report viewer in Visual Studio using crystal report. Accidentally something happened and all the fonts in format editor properties were replaced with only device font 10cpi,12cpi and 17cpi in the dropdown. Need help to get the fonts back

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the default printer on that machine is set to a printer that can support the fonts you need. Crystal renders reports based on printer driver.